# NoSuchMethodError occuring in normal java project and not in J2EE project ( Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

The Java program I wrote is giving a NoSuchMethodError when I run it in a normal Java Project but it is running properly when run inside a J2EE Web Project. The NoSuchMethodError is on a method written by me. It doesn't use any of the webtools. I have no clue why this is happening. Any insights on why this occurs? Also the program doesnt use J2EE components. By chance i ran it in a web project and it worked perfectly.

Software used:
1.Eclipse Indigo 3.7
2.jdk 1.7 ,jre7
3. Tomcat 7

EDIT 1.:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:x.y.opinion.db.SentenceAccumulator.addSentenceForDocuId(ILcom/google/api/translate/Language;)V
at com.x.y.repo.RepoBuilder.processDocument(RepoBuilder.java:350)
at com.x.y.db.DataLoadJob.loadData(DataLoadJob.java:382)
at com.x.y.db.loadDataFromBackEnd.loadData(loadDataFromBackEnd.java:51)
at com.x.y.db.loadDataFromBackEnd.loadBackEnd(loadDataFromBackEnd.java:28)
at sample.main(sample.java:37)
```

EDIT 2. :
 When i debug the program, it is asking me to add the source files for the jars. Below that it is saying

```
// Compiled from RepoBuilder.java (version 1.6 : 50.0, super bit)
```

But it was compiled using 1.7 only. I'm damn sure!

Comment: Post the full stacktrace .

Comment: Also the code that causes the problem might be useful.

Comment: add dependent jar files

Comment: Added the stack trace. The jar files are all added. Its running perfectly in a Web-project but not in a normal project.

Comment: Please post the complete correct stack trace. The stack trace posted by you is incorrect and senseless for help.

Comment: Did you run the code through an obfuscator?

Comment: @UwePlonus : posted the clear stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodError` happens when you write code for one version of a class and then run it with another that does not have a the method that you use. [From the documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html)

> Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.
>
> Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

Make sure that you have the same versions of the library that is giving the error in both environments.

If the error is thrown for a method that you wrote yourself you have a mixture of classes from different builds. Try deleting all class files and doing a clean build.

Comment: Both are using the same jre, same build and run-time path. I triple checked

Comment: If they were you wouldn't get this error; from somewhere, somehow, a different version of this particular class is getting loaded.